# Selenium, webdriver - after can't find xpath Should the browser close. python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, helper

Hello iam new and i have a one question.it's about an account creator for my website. ..

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="elInput_email"]')
email.send_keys(email_str)
```

sometimes show errors: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="elInput_email"]

closes the browser without checking how do I do it best?

i try

```
if not driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="elInput_email"]'):driver.close() 
else: email.send_keys(email_str)
```

but not works.

I would like the webdrive (browser) to be closed if it cannot locate XPATH.

Comment: why can't you just wrap your test in exception handling and close the browser as part of finally.

Comment: How can I close driverweb if xpath is NOT found? I don't have that much experience :)

Comment: Provided the pseduo code below, you can use `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'xpath_goes_here')))` pretty much for all the elements when navigating or loading a page. So that the script will wait for max of the specified time before going to the finally block.

Comment: I don't see the code with `finally` implementation.

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo code.

**Imports needed for Explcit wait**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Script should be**

```
# initiate your driver instance

# navigate to the page

try:
    # wait for the element using explicit wait(waiting for max of 10 seconds)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    email = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="elInput_email"]')))
    email.send_keys(email_str)
finally:
    # close the browser here
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left hand side in my answer. Feel free to upvote the answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: Thank for your Answer i got Error.
  File "C:\test.py", line 24
    wait = DriverWait(driver, 10)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: It should be `WebDriverWait` not `DriverWait`

Comment: Just tested. Error message also comes with

    wait = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)

Comment: Make sure you have the right indentation. The error says, the indentation is not correct in that line. If you are still facing issue, please update the question with the current code. so that we can check what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Thanks right. but i got now other error 

  File "C:\test.py", line 27
    finally:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, we can't help you without looking at the code, as we don't know what line#27 is.

Comment: Hello line 27 is "finally:" <--- 

`# initiate your driver instance

# navigate to the page

try:
    # wait for the element using explicit wait(waiting for max of 10 seconds)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    email = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="elInput_email"]')))
    email.send_keys(email_str)
finally:
    # close the browser here
    driver.quit(`

Comment: Can you hop in [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/213726/selenium-webdriver-after-cant-find-xpath-should-the-browser-close?tab=general) please.

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.  :( 

Can you here coming sir?
https://stin.to/cq7qt

Comment: Sorry, can access the link from my network. Please update the question with your latest code.

Comment: make sure the driver initialized outside the `try/finally` block.

Comment: Did you checked my updated answer with the comment lines.

Comment: Please delete the comment. let me know when you are online, I will find a way to chat with you in SO.

Comment: Ok but now works with only try: email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="elInput_email"]')
email.send_keys(email_str) 
 excpet Exception as e: driver.close()